# SignalR 2.0.0 / JsonSerializerSettings: The reader's MaxDepth of 20 has been exceeded

Tags: signalr

I am receiving the following error when sending a message to the server using **SignalR 2.0.0**:

> SignalR: The reader's MaxDepth of 20 has been exceeded.

I am using Unity for DI and have tried registering an instance of the JsonSerializer:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(
    typeof (JsonSerializer),
    () => JsonSerializer.Create(
         new JsonSerializerSettings
         {
             ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(),
             MaxDepth = int.MaxValue
         }));
```

I have event tried this:

```
object IDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType)
{
    var result = _container.IsRegistered(serviceType) ? _container.Resolve(serviceType) : base.GetService(serviceType);

    if (result != null && result.GetType().FullName.Equals("Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        ((Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer) result).MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The error just will not go away.  It is as though SignalR is simply using another instance of the JsonSerializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I logged the following issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/2911

It seems as though it is a known issue so our solution was to replace the SignalR bit that pushes our messages to our back-end with a Web-Api Ajax POST.